# Simple way to download Google Chrome/Chromium source code

Tags: chromium

I thought this would be easy but I can't find any link to a simple tar.gz/tar.bz2/zip archive.

Chrome uses some custom tools like `build_depot` to even download the source code. But I don't want to compile the source code, I just want to see how they do something in the source code.

So all I need is the source code download link, in the simplest possible form. Is there any way at all to find a zip archive containing all the source code, without reading howtos and  building and compiling tools just to be able to download it?

Even old versions would do. I don't need to compile anything, I just need the code, and there are no download links to that.

Answer (score 19):

On the [Get the code](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) page you have a link  to the [source tarball](http://chromium-browser-source.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium_tarball.html).

Comment: Is there an option that is still maintained? The README inside says `The archive was produced on Wed May  1 01:02:57 2013`—that's over a year old now.

Comment: didnt even try to download this tarbal,as also the mentioned page doesn#t have a link for a single download anymore and so I assume they dont maintain it anymore for whatever reason

Answer (score 10):

Here is an updated way to do it

```
git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git chromium
```

The `depth` argument results in a shallow clone so that you don't pull down the massive history. You can remove it if you want full copy.

This still requires `git`, but it doesn't require you to install a bunch of custom tools that may mess up your whole system.

Answer (score 6):

Looked at it and it seems on the get the code page there is no mention of a single simple file download - presumably because it's for people actually willing to develop and work with these sources, and the code-base is complex and needs extra tools (it's similar to Android, which is managed by git but there is a special tool to manage the multitude of single repositories that need to be orchestrated).

So if your just curious to look at one version of the sources, you can browse the code to the tag/revision you like and get the tgz link. For example, the last known good revision lkgr: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr

Answer (score 5):

**it WORKS.** (spoon feed documentation version 1)

**Step 1:**

---

[image]

> wget https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools.zip
>
> unzip_to C:\depot_tools.zip

**Step 2:**

---

> cmd.exe
>
> gclient

[image]
[image]

**Step 3:**

---

> setup environment

[image]

**Step 4:**

---

[image]

**Step 5:**

---

> step 4 is active, downloading source code, can take above 8GB to 15GB
>
> wait for 4 hours

**Step 6:**

---

> download visual studio 2013
>   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx
>
> make sure its update 1 or update 4

[image]

> setup the environment value

[image]

**Step 7:**

---

> gclient runhooks

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/30314754/285594)

> wait half an hour

[image]

**Step 8:**

---

> compile/build
>
> wait 2 hour

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's an enormous archive at https://gsdview.appspot.com/chromium-browser-official/. It contains all versions starting at 14.0, including every daily subversion (14.0.783.0, 14.0.784.0, etc), up to 75.0.3755.0 released yesterday (as of writing).

Unfortunately, the interface is paginated and contains no page jump, so you'll need ~30 clicks on Next Page to reach latest Chrome; as of writing, the quick link to latest is https://gsdview.appspot.com/chromium-browser-official/?marker=chromium-74.0.3711.0.tar.xz.hashe%40.

These tarballs are also .xz rather than .gz; the accepted answer links to a 2.2GiB download, while 75.0.3755.0 at the archive is 721MiB.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mirror at: https://github.com/chromium/chromium

Try:

`git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/chromium/chromium.git`