# Error when try to compile Chromium

Tags: chromium, ninja

I try to use the command `ninja -C out/Debug chrome` to compile Chromium.

However the error msg says that:

```
ninja error loading 'build.ninja': the system cannot find the file specified 
ninja Entering dictory 'out/Debug'
```

Could I know what's the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The out directory and its contents (including build.ninja) are created by running

> python build\gyp_chromium

or

> gclient runhooks

Executing either command from within /src should allow your compile to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows machine!

When I was running `gn gen out/Default` it also gave me an error:

```
ERROR at //build/config/win/visual_studio_version.gni:27:7: Script returned non-zero exit code.
      exec_script("../../vs_toolchain.py", [ "get_toolchain_dir" ], "scope")
      ^----------
Current dir: D:/Chromium/src/out/Goma/
Command: C:/Python27/python.exe -- D:/Chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py get_toolchain_dir
Returned 1 and printed out:




Please follow the instructions at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md
```

I did the following steps and it worked for me.

1. Set this variable. [Reference](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460462#c8) (not sure about its purpose yet)

`set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0`

2. Run the command `gn gen out/Default`
3. Run the build command again

`autoninja -C out/Default chrome`

It is also recommended to run `gclient sync` from `out/Default` directory.

Answer (score 0):

After the switch to "gn" you could try:

gn gen out/Debug

Comment: This answer will be more useful if you add some explanation.